# ¿Cómo respetar espacios en un texto ya formado en Unity?

Tags: unity, idioma

Tengo un cuadro de texto en mi `canvas` pero cuando lo traduzco a otro idioma, se traduce sin respetar los espacios y demas.

La conversion de idioma lo hago a traves del tipico diccionario incrustado como `public Text[] Text;` , ¿hay alguna forma de poner como en `HTML` algo similar a \n o algo para forzar los saltos de línea tal como estaba con el idioma original?

Answer (score -1):

Si, tal como parece, el texto lo estás añadiendo vía script, '\n' funcionará correctamente para el salto de línea, así que puedes añadirlo en las traducciones. Asegúrate de que la caja de texto tiene la altura suficientemente o el texto se cortará.

```
// Tu objeto del tipo Text
myText.text = "Primera línea\nSegunda línea";
```

Comment: No lo estoy añadiendo via script, si no en el mismo unity